# Modal Popup out of place

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a modal popup which is out of place as soon as the keyboard pops up.

[image]

How can I avoid this behavior?

The popup is called like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
```

And in the popup's view controller, I say:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 403, 340);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you remove the line `self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 403, 340);`?

Comment: No, same issue. And then the dimentions of the modal are not correct. It's too big, but even then it moves to the left... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to present viewController like this,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard       = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
LoginViewController *loginVC   = (LoginViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue"];
loginVC.modalTransitionStyle   = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:loginVC animated:YES];
```

**Edit**

You can use your original code `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];` for presenting view if above is also giving you same result.

I checked with all possible solution and found that `becomeFirstResponder` might cause issue. So just place code `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewDidLoad` or in `viewWillAppear` method. Make sure it should not be in `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: UIStoryboard *storyboard1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil]; it gives me an "Expression expected" error...

Comment: Ok it didn't work, not it just jumps to the other side of the screen... :( And I don't understand why I can't use the segue itself, because the segue is defined to be a FormSheet Modal, so it should be the same effect...

Comment: Hi, ok now it doesn't move to the left, but now the view is half hidden behind the keyboard.. How can I move the view up?

Comment: @CyberK The problem of your posted question is solved here. So you should ask another question on SO for above query. We can help you on new question :).

Comment: Ok will do that! Thanks!